# Removing Attributes on ServletContext (Application Scope) in Tomcat manually

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, application-scope

Hi Stackoverflow peeps,

I'm just wondering if there are way to remove **application scope** attributes in your web app. I know how to delete it in a code way, like using this:

```
ServletContext application = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
application.removeAttribute("sampleInfo");
```

But the problem is the application is currently on the production now. So, is there a way to remove it like flushing something on the server side (Tomcat), because I tried to shutdown and start the tomcat, but the attribute is still there.

Comment: Why do you think reboot of application should help this attribute to go away? If this attribute is in the application context, then find a place where it was added and remove that line, and then restart of the tomcat will help.

Comment: What are you trying to remove? Something your application put there, or something Tomcat put there?